# Quantum error correction terminology

Tags: error-correction, terminology-and-notation

I'm asking for help to clear up something, but instead of asking a question, I'm just writing my attempt of a definition below. I assume it's not this simple, and the below is not the correct understanding, so I'm hoping someone could get me on the right track:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $L(H)$ the linear operators on $H$. Assume that $\dim H=n$, so that $L(H)\simeq M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

A quantum code space $C$ is a linear subspace of $C\subseteq H$ and an error space $E$ is a linear subspace $E\subseteq L(H)$.

**Definition** Let $C$ be a quantum code space. Let $y\in L(H)$. Then $C$ is $y$-error correcting if there exists $x\in L(H)$ such that $xy\xi=\xi$ for all $\xi\in C$. Moreover, if $E$ is an error space, then $C$ is $E$-error correcting if $C$ is $y$-error correcting for every $y\in E$.

**Fact** Let $C$ be a quantum code space. Let $y,z\in L(H)$. If $C$ is both $y$- and $z$-error correcting, then $C$ is $(\alpha y+\beta z)$-error correcting for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$.

In light of this fact (which I'm not able to show from the above), one may just consider a set $\mathcal{E}$ of operators that spans $E$.

This came up as I was reading about unitary error bases (and nice error bases), and wanted to know why it's called "error bases", and therefore I would like to have a formal definition.

New: (1) To be clear, I would like a definition saying this: Let $C$ be a linear subspace of $H$ and $\mathcal{E}$ a set of operators in $L(H)$. Then $C$ is called $\mathcal{E}$-error correcting if [fill in the correct condition].

(2) Maybe my confusion has something to do with error correction for quantum channels. If $\Phi$ is a quantum channel on $L(H)$ and $C$ is a linear subspace of $H$, then $C$ is $\Phi$-error correcting if there exists a quantum channel $\mathcal{R}$ on $L(H)$ such that $\mathcal{R}\circ\Phi$ is the identity when restricted to $L(C)$ (embedded into $L(H)$ in the obvious way).

(3) In this regard, does the Knill-Laflamme also makes sense for error operators? The way it's usually stated is by giving conditions on a set of operators $\mathcal{E}$ that give a Kraus decomposition of a quantum channel $\Phi$. In this setting, for a linear subspace $C$ of $H$, is $C$ $\Phi$-error correcting if $C$ is $\mathcal{E}$-error correcting in the "error operator" sense? One difference is that for a quantum channel it's required that $\sum_\mathcal{E}E_i^*E_i=I$, while this is not required in the "error operator" setup.

Comment: I think you may be missing something from your definition regarding error detection. You are right about the linearity of error correction, and one of the consequences is that you can always take $y$ to be unitary (for example). But then, for all $y$, there exists an $x=y^\dagger$ that would let you correct. The issue is in detecting which error has occurred. For any syndrome, there are always multiple possible "corrections", some which send you in the right direction, others which create a logical error.

Comment: You need an error space $E$ for which all members can be detected and which return you to the correct state, given the detection. This, at least for non-degenerate codes, means each $y\in E$ should have a different syndrome.

Comment: @DaftWullie thanks for your response! Yes, in my definition attempt, the $x$ depends on $y$, so different $y$'s could produce different $x$'s. My question is more about formalism than application, so for this definition, I don't care about how hard it is to find the left inverse $x$ of $y$ on $C$, only what it means, with mathematical precision, to be error-correcting. I also updated the opening posts with some more aspects.